# How to use groupBy on Object Key in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How to use the groupBy on ``` array``, ```assets`` based on `object key` in angular which is the `PRN, PRN1, PRN2`..

here's the code for my list.component.ts

first I filter it where it `param === 2019` the current date.

***list.component.ts***

```
this.rowData.push(
      {
        'code': 'Machine 1', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-19 02:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 1', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-19 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 2', 'assetCode': 'PRN 1', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-20 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 3', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-21 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 4', 'assetCode': 'PRN 1', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-22 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 5', 'assetCode': 'PRN 2', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-23 00:00:00'
      },
    );

this.rowData = this.rowData.filter((item: any) => {
      return format(item.date, 'YYYY') === param;
    });
    const merge = (array: any) => array.reduce((results: any, item: any) => {
      const data = results.find((i: any) => i.code === item.code);
      if (data) {
        data.assets[item.assetCode] = (data.assets[item.assetCode] || 0) + item.assetCount;
      } else {
        results.push({
          code: item.code,
          date: item.date,
          assets: { [item.assetCode]: item.assetCount }
        });
      }
      return results;
    }, []);

    this.rowData = merge(this.rowData);

this.rowData.forEach((key: any) => {
        console.log(key);

});
```

What I want is `group` it, based on the Object keys like `PRN/PRN1/PRN2`.

should be like this (example)

```
{
 PRN: [{
    'code': 'Machine 1',
    'assetCount': 2,
    'date': '2019-01-19'
  }],
PRN 1: [{
        'code': 'Machine 2',
        'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-19'
      }]
}
```

***console***
[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Convert results to object instead of array, i have excluded some of your logic in the below code, you can include it

```
const merge = (array: any) => array.reduce((results: any, item: any) => {

    results[item.assetCode] = [{
      code: item.code,
      date: item.date,
      assetCount: item.assetCount
    }]
  return results;
}, {});

this.rowData = merge(this.rowData);
console.log(this.rowData);
```

Comment: how will you push on it?

Comment: It's not array, an object so adding keys(PNR) to the object

Comment: {
 PRN: [{
    'code': 'Machine 1',
    'assetCount': 2,
    'date': '2019-01-19'
  }],
PRN 1: [{
        'code': 'Machine 2',
        'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-19'
      }]
i tried to achieve above result it worked, you can append whichever data you need

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain an object and you can start putting the values in to that Object by making assetcode as key.

```
const obj = {};
for (const [index, data] of rowData.entries()) {
  // console.log(data);
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(data.assetCode)) {
    obj[data.assetCode].push(data);
  } else {
    obj[data.assetCode] = [];
    obj[data.assetCode].push(data);
  }
}
```